# What does 'A right tabstop should be set at 6.0” with a dot leader.' mean in LaTeX terms?

Tags: table-of-contents

My school's thesis guidelines were written for people using MS word.  For the most part, I'm able to decipher how to abide by the guidelines in LaTeX but this particular note is perplexing.

What does 'A right tabstop should be set at 6.0” with a dot leader.' mean in LaTeX terms?

How do I implement what they are asking me to do in LaTeX?

Here is the relevant page in my thesis guidelines:

[image: Thesis Guidlines]

And the code I've attempted to use to replicate it.

```
\contentsmargin{1.5in}
\titlecontents{part}
[0pt] 
{}
{\thecontentslabel}
{} 
{\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\contentspage}
[]  

\titlecontents{chapter}[24pt]
{}
{\thecontentslabel\enspace}
{}
{\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\contentspage}
[]

\titlecontents{section}[48pt]
{}
{\thecontentslabel\enspace
}
{}
{\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\contentspage} 
[]
```

The page numbers don't align properly and I'm not really sure how to replicate the part that just says "Chapter" in the Thesis guidlines

Comment: Welcome! `6.0` what? What's the context? Is this about a contents listing of some kind?

Comment: I assume that the right tabstop should be set at `6 inches` from the lefthand margin. It is possible that the other directives will either confirm or deny that assumption.

Comment: Yes `6.0″` (double prime after the number) is standard convention for "6.0 inches". A [dot leader](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Leader_(typography)&oldid=738606876) looks like "............." leading up to the tab stop (often seen in table of contents and the like). TeX naturally supports leaders (with `\leaders`); I'm not sure whether it's conventionally used/“recommended” in LaTeX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how to set "a right tabstop [..] at 6.0" with a dot leader" in Word:

1. Let's assume you have an 8.5" x 11" (letter) page setup. Then the default margins (there is no mention of margin settings visible in your image) would show the following ruler in the top of the page view:

   [image]
2. Double-right click anywhere in this ruler to set a left (default) tab stop (here at about 3.5"):

   [image]
3. It should also open up the tab stop dialog box (if not, double-left click on the tab stop to open it up or follow the ribbon sequence Layout > Paragraph > Tabs; left/first image). Hit "Clear all" and then add the 6" tab stop (right/second image):

   [image]
   [image]

   Press OK.
4. This is what that alignment tab results in for the output:

   [image]

   Note the ragged-left alignment of the elements (page numbers) X, YYYYYYY, ZZZ.

The above implies right-aligned page numbers in the ToC with dot leaders right up to the page number. Here's how to achieve that with [`tocloft`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft):

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\usepackage{lipsum}% Just for this example
\sloppy% Just for this example

% Format \chapter fill/leader in ToC
\renewcommand{\cftchapfillnum}[1]{{\cftchapleader}\nobreak{\cftchappagefont #1}\cftchapafterpnum\par}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\mdseries}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\mdseries}
% Format \section fill/leader in ToC
\renewcommand{\cftsecfillnum}[1]{{\cftsecleader}\nobreak{\cftsecpagefont #1}\cftsecafterpnum\par}
% Format \subsection fill/leader in ToC
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecfillnum}[1]{{\cftsubsecleader}\nobreak{\cftsubsecpagefont #1}\cftsubsecafterpnum\par}

% Set dot separation to be the same for all entries in the ToC
\renewcommand{\cftdotsep}{1}% Default is 4.5
% Based on a 6" tab alignment, you need a 1/2" space on the right of each page number
\newcommand{\tocrmarginindent}{\hspace*{0.5in}}
\renewcommand{\cftchapafterpnum}{\tocrmarginindent}
\renewcommand{\cftsecafterpnum}{\tocrmarginindent}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecafterpnum}{\tocrmarginindent}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First chapter}\lipsum[1-50]
\section{First section}\lipsum[1-50]
\subsection{First subsection}\lipsum[1-50]
\subsection{Second subsection}\lipsum[1-50]
\subsection{Last subsection}\lipsum[1-50]
\section{Second section}\lipsum[1-50]
\subsection{First subsection}\lipsum[1-50]
\subsection{Second subsection}\lipsum[1-50]
\subsection{Last subsection}\lipsum[1-50]
\section{Last section}\lipsum[1-50]
\subsection{First subsection}\lipsum[1-50]
\subsection{Second subsection}\lipsum[1-50]
\subsection{Third subsection}\lipsum[1-50]
\subsection{Last subsection}\lipsum[1-50]

\chapter{Second chapter}\lipsum[1-50]
\section{First section}\lipsum[1-50]
\subsection{First subsection}\lipsum[1-50]
\subsection{Second subsection}\lipsum[1-50]
\subsection{Last subsection}\lipsum[1-50]
\section{Second section}\lipsum[1-50]
\subsection{First subsection}\lipsum[1-50]
\subsection{Second subsection}\lipsum[1-50]
\subsection{Last subsection}\lipsum[1-50]
\section{Last section}\lipsum[1-50]
\subsection{First subsection}\lipsum[1-50]
\subsection{Second subsection}\lipsum[1-50]
\subsection{Last subsection}\lipsum[1-50]

\chapter{Last chapter}\lipsum[1-50]
\section{First section}\lipsum[1-50]
\subsection{First subsection}\lipsum[1-50]
\subsection{Second subsection}\lipsum[1-50]
\subsection{Last subsection}\lipsum[1-50]
\section{Second section}\lipsum[1-50]
\subsection{First subsection}\lipsum[1-50]
\subsection{Second subsection}\lipsum[1-50]
\subsection{Last subsection}\lipsum[1-50]
\section{Last section}\lipsum[1-50]
\subsection{First subsection}\lipsum[1-50]
\subsection{Second subsection}\lipsum[1-50]
\subsection{Last subsection}\lipsum[1-50]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a general-purpose solution, that is not tied to any particular document class or template:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{changepage}
\newcommand\mytocitem[2]{\noindent #1\,\dotfill\,#2\par}
\begin{document}
\begin{adjustwidth}{0.5in}{0.5in} % adjust values as needed
{\centering TABLE OF CONTENTS\par}
\null
\mytocitem{ABSTRACT}{iii}
\null
\mytocitem{DEDICATION}{v}
\null
\mytocitem{ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS}{vi}
\null
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{document}
```

The `\null` creates a blank line. In the `adjustwidth` environment, the two arguments define how much the table is indented from the usual left and right margins. So, you can change the values from 0.5in to whatever you need, in order to get the "tab stop" at the correct location.

EDIT: Note that this is not for automatically generated Table of Contents. It is strictly for situations where you manually create the table.

[image: result of code]

Answer (score 1):

A right tab stop means the text is right-aligned 6 inches from the left margin. The instructions also say the page numbers should be aligned with the right margin, which means `textwidth=6in`. A dot leader is equivalent to `\dotfill`, but that should be the default for most standard packages. If you set `\textwidth` (and other margins) using the `geometry` package, the default `\tableofcontents` should be close to what you need. For other fine-grained tweaks to the TOC, take a look at the `tocloft` package documentation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[letterpaper,textwidth=6in]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]